# How to load custom fonts in a Javafx application

Tags: javafx, fonts, fxml

I am trying to load custom Fonts to my JavaFx application and it worked one time. After I restarted my IDE the Fonts disappeared and the standard fonts were loaded

```
Font ZOMBEY = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourcesAsStream("css/ZOMBYE.otf"), 20;
Font TradeWinds =   Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("css/TradeWinds-Regular.ttf"), 20);
Font Bock = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("css/Bock_Personaluse.otf"), 20);
```

[Project-Structure looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaNvr.png)

Comment: You shoud check separately whether 'getClass().getResourcesAsStream("css/ZOMBYE.otf")' actually returns something which in not null.

Comment: It actually returns null but i dont know why and how i could fix this.

Comment: Obvioul.y it can't find the resource because your URL is false but nobody will be able to help you with this until we know your project file structure.

Comment: Project structure is updated

Comment: According to your project structure the font files are simply not in your 'css' folder.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sample/fonts/ZOMBYE.otf");
assert is != null;
```

Don't forget to enable assertions via `-ea` VM option.

Note the '/' in front of 'sample' and I wonder how you got your code compiled because there is no method `getResourcesAsStream` (note the 's' after Resource) like in your first code line.